# how to make sure that a thread waiting for an event from two different timers will not miss any of the events?

Tags: c, pthreads

I want to create a thread which waits for an event signaled by two timers on their expiration. When the thread receives the signal it has to do some image processing. I started off with the following code. (this is the very basic implementation in which thread displays the messages instead of doing image processing )

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>


struct itimerspec ts1,ts2;
struct sigevent se1,se2;

timer_t timerId1,timerId2;

pthread_cond_t imageProcessCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t imageProcessMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* imageProcessThread()
{
  int status = 0;
  int i = 0;

  while(i<2){

    status = pthread_mutex_lock (&imageProcessMutex);
    if(status != 0){
      perror("pthread_mutex_lock\n");
      exit(status);
    }

    status = pthread_cond_wait (&imageProcessCond, &imageProcessMutex);
    if (status != 0){
      perror("pthread_cond_wait\n");
      exit(status);
    }

    printf("signal received %s\n",__TIME__);

    i++;

    status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&imageProcessMutex);
    if(status != 0){
    perror("pthread_mutex_unlock\n");
    exit(status);
    }

  }

}

void timerFunc1 ()
{
  int status = 0;

  status = pthread_mutex_lock (&imageProcessMutex);
  if (status != 0){
    perror("pthread_mutex_lock\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("timer1 took lock %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_cond_signal (&imageProcessCond);
  if (status != 0){
    perror("pthread_cond_signal\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("timer1 signalled %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&imageProcessMutex);
  if (status != 0){
    perror("pthread_mutex_unlock\n");
    exit(status);
  }

  printf("timer1 released lock %s\n",__TIME__);
}

void timerFunc2 ()
{
  int status = 0;

  status = pthread_mutex_lock (&imageProcessMutex);
  if (status != 0){
    perror("pthread_mutex_lock\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("timer2 took lock %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_cond_signal (&imageProcessCond);
  if (status != 0){
    perror("pthread_cond_signal\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("timer2 signalled %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&imageProcessMutex);
  if (status != 0){
    perror("pthread_mutex_unlock\n");
    exit(status);
  }

  printf("timer2 released lock %s\n",__TIME__);
}

int main()
{

  int status = 0;
  pthread_t tImageProcessId;

  se1.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  se1.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerId1;
  se1.sigev_notify_function = timerFunc1;
  se1.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

  ts1.it_value.tv_sec = 20;
  ts1.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  ts1.it_interval.tv_sec = 20;
  ts1.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

  se2.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  se2.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerId2;
  se2.sigev_notify_function = timerFunc2;
  se2.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

  ts2.it_value.tv_sec = 20;
  ts2.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  ts2.it_interval.tv_sec = 20;
  ts2.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

  status = pthread_create((&tImageProcessId), NULL, &imageProcessThread, NULL);
  if(status!= 0){
    perror("pthread_create\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  status = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &se1, &timerId1);
  if (status != 0){
    perror("timer_create\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  status = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &se2, &timerId2);
  if (status != 0){
    perror("timer_create\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  status = timer_settime(timerId1, 0, &ts1, 0);
  if (status != 0){
    perror("timer_create\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  status = timer_settime(timerId2, 0, &ts2, 0);
  if (status != 0){
    perror("timer_create\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

sleep(80);

}
```

I have configured both the timers for the same time interval (I have simulated this condition only for testing purpose)In actual scenario the timers will be configured for different time intervals but there might be a situation in which both of them expire at the same time)

What my understanding was:

1. Thread takes the lock, enters wait state and internally releases the lock
2. timer1 and timer2 expires almost at the same time and both try to take the lock. Let us suppose timer1 succeeds in taking the lock and timer 2 is kept in wait state.
3. Timer1 which has the lock signals the event and releases the lock
4. The thread which is waiting for the event, takes the lock, displays the message and releases lock and again goes to wait state.
5. Timer2 which was kept in wait state by timer 1 takes the lock, signals the event and releases the lock
   6.Again thread comes into picture and displays the message

But When I ran the above code, thread is actually missing the event signaled by timer1.

This is the output which I got

timer1 took lock 11:40:20

timer1 signaled 11:40:20

timer2 took lock 11:40:20

timer2 signaled 11:40:20

signal received 11:40:20

timer2 released lock 11:40:20

timer1 released lock 11:40:20

The event signaled by timer1 is getting lost. As soon as timer1 releases the lock, timer 2 is taking the lock and thread is not getting executed.

How do I make sure that the control goes from timer1 to thread and then to timer2?
Is there any other way of implementing this?
Please help me with this problem

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Arpitha

Answer (score 1):

The imageProcessThread function has a synchronization breach. From the imageProcessMutex mutex unlock until its next lock (the second "while" iteration), the code is not synchronized.
Probably the second notification is sent from the TimerFunc2 function when imageProcessThread does not wait on the imageProcessCond and this notification goes to noway.
Another important thing is spurious wakeups. The pthread_cond_wait may wake up even if the TimerFunc functions do not send notifications. It does not happen in your case (according to the output), but may happen under other conditions and should be treated properly: when a notification (real or spurious) reached the pthread_cond_wait check the predicate again.

Your code can be slightly changed to fix the above leaks.
The main idea is to share the local i variable among the functions, letting your timers to increment it and to protect the "while" waiting loop completely.

```
struct itimerspec ts1,ts2;
struct sigevent se1,se2;

timer_t timerId1,timerId2;

pthread_cond_t imageProcessCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t imageProcessMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
int i = 0;

void* imageProcessThread()
{
  int status = 0;
  //int i = 0;

  status = pthread_mutex_lock (&imageProcessMutex);
  while(i<2){
    //status = pthread_mutex_lock (&imageProcessMutex);
    status = pthread_cond_wait (&imageProcessCond, &imageProcessMutex);
    printf("signal received %s\n",__TIME__);
    //i++;
    //status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&imageProcessMutex);
  }
  status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&imageProcessMutex);
}

void timerFunc1 ()
{
  int status = 0;

  status = pthread_mutex_lock (&imageProcessMutex);
  i++;
  printf("timer1 took lock %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_cond_signal (&imageProcessCond);
  printf("timer1 signalled %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&imageProcessMutex);
  printf("timer1 released lock %s\n",__TIME__);
}

void timerFunc2 ()
{
  int status = 0;

  status = pthread_mutex_lock (&imageProcessMutex);
  i++;
  printf("timer2 took lock %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_cond_signal (&imageProcessCond);
  printf("timer2 signalled %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&imageProcessMutex);
  printf("timer2 released lock %s\n",__TIME__);
}

int main()
{

  int status = 0;
  pthread_t tImageProcessId;

  se1.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  se1.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerId1;
  se1.sigev_notify_function = timerFunc1;
  se1.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

  ts1.it_value.tv_sec = 20;
  ts1.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  ts1.it_interval.tv_sec = 20;
  ts1.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

  se2.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  se2.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerId2;
  se2.sigev_notify_function = timerFunc2;
  se2.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

  ts2.it_value.tv_sec = 20;
  ts2.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  ts2.it_interval.tv_sec = 20;
  ts2.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

  status = pthread_create((&tImageProcessId), NULL, &imageProcessThread, NULL);
  status = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &se1, &timerId1);
  status = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &se2, &timerId2);
  status = timer_settime(timerId1, 0, &ts1, 0);
  status = timer_settime(timerId2, 0, &ts2, 0);


sleep(80);

}
```

Another minor notification is about the

```
__TIME__
```

It is a compilation time, so your output will show the same time values in each line.

I would also recommend to read about barrier synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply

Even with the above code, i am missing one event. I need to receive the events sequentially one after the other.

If take one more lock before locking imageProcessMutex it is working fine. Both the events are received by the image process thread. please have look at the below code.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/signal.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

struct itimerspec ts1,ts2;
struct sigevent se1,se2;

timer_t timerId1,timerId2;

pthread_cond_t imageProcessCond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t imageProcessMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

pthread_mutex_t mainMutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void* imageProcessThread()
{
  int status = 0;
  int i =0;

  status = pthread_mutex_lock (&imageProcessMutex);

  while(i<2){

    status = pthread_cond_wait (&imageProcessCond, &imageProcessMutex);

    printf("signal received %s\n",__TIME__);

    i++;
  }

  status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&imageProcessMutex);
}

void timerFunc1 ()
{
  int status = 0;

  status = pthread_mutex_lock (&mainMutex);

  status = pthread_mutex_lock (&imageProcessMutex);

  printf("timer1 took image process lock %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_cond_signal (&imageProcessCond);

  printf("timer1 signalled %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&imageProcessMutex);

  printf("timer1 released image process lock %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&mainMutex);

}

void timerFunc2 ()
{
  int status = 0;

  status = pthread_mutex_lock (&mainMutex);

  status = pthread_mutex_lock (&imageProcessMutex);

  printf("timer2 took image process lock %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_cond_signal (&imageProcessCond);

  printf("timer2 signalled %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&imageProcessMutex);

  printf("timer2 released image lock %s\n",__TIME__);

  status = pthread_mutex_unlock (&mainMutex);

}

int main()
{

  int status = 0;
  pthread_t tImageProcessId;

  se1.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  se1.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerId1;
  se1.sigev_notify_function = timerFunc1;
  se1.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;


  ts1.it_value.tv_sec = 20;
  ts1.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  ts1.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
  ts1.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

  se2.sigev_notify = SIGEV_THREAD;
  se2.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerId2;
  se2.sigev_notify_function = timerFunc2;
  se2.sigev_notify_attributes = NULL;

  ts2.it_value.tv_sec = 20;
  ts2.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
  ts2.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
  ts2.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

  status = pthread_create((&tImageProcessId), NULL, &imageProcessThread, NULL);

  status = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &se1, &timerId1);

  status = timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &se2, &timerId2);

  status = timer_settime(timerId1, 0, &ts1, 0);

  status = timer_settime(timerId2, 0, &ts2, 0);

  sleep(80);
}
```

I got the following output

timer1 took image process lock 14:14:28

timer1 signalled 14:14:28

signal received 14:14:28

timer1 released image process lock 14:14:28

timer2 took image process lock 14:14:28

timer2 signalled 14:14:28

timer2 released image lock 14:14:28

signal received 14:14:28

With this i am not missing any of the events.

I just want to know whether this can be implemented without using pthread_cond_wait and pthread_cond_signal.

Also Barrier synchronization which you referred is mainly used to bring the synchronization between many threads (2 or more threads). But In my case there is only one thread which is waiting for the event.So i am not sure barrier synchronization will be the correct approach. Please refer the link.

http://geekswithblogs.net/jolson/archive/2009/02/09/an-intro-to-barrier.aspx

Thanks and Regards,

Arpitha